# Running Appium tests in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, appium, appium-android, appium-ios

I am starting to learn Appium for Android and iOS apps automation. And now I have stopped on setting up CI/CD for tests using Jenkins.

1. I  can't understand how to generate new .apk (Android) and .ipa (iOS) files for used them in my tests. I want to run tests for new versions of apps
2. If I have set up Jenkins locally - is there is possibility to shared reports with my team?

Please, help me!)

Answer (score 0):

> I can't understand how to generate new .apk (Android) and .ipa (iOS) files for used them in my tests. I want to run tests for new versions of apps

You can create scripts to run your pipeline to build `.apk` and `.ipa` files and then fetch and copy the files to your test automation project via jenkins pipeline,

> If I have set up Jenkins locally - is there is possibility to shared reports with my team?

You can create Slack/ Email hooks to send the configured report to notify the team upon execution.

Preferably use `Slack` rather than `Email` for report notification.